# Конвертация из yyyy-mm-dd в dd-mm-yyyy в Java?

Tags: java, дата

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как сконвертировать из yyyy-mm-dd в dd-mm-yyyy ?
Есть вот это 2015-08-23
Нужно ее представить в таком виде: 23.08.2015
Прошу пните меня в правильном направлении.

Comment: Подозрительно, что вы преобразовываете между текстом и текстом. У вас должен быть объект типа `LocalDate`. Расскажите более широкий контекст задачи.

Comment: Я получаю с сервера в xml дату в формате: 22.08.2015
Мне нужно ее увеличить на один день. 
я сначала сконвертировал в 2015-08-23. 
увеличил. 
теперь нужно обратно.

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(Date, dateTimeFormatter);
LocalDate localDateNext = localDate.plusDays(1);

Comment: Ну, а зачем вам строковое представление? Получили дату, распарсили её в `LocalDate` и работаете с ней дальше. Какой смысл конвертировать в другой формат перед тем, как парсить?

Comment: Сервер принимает только в таком формате: 22.08.2015. 
Мне нужно нарощенную дату отправить на сервер. 
Например получил 22.08.2015. Нарастил. И отправил 23.08.2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо ничего конвертировать. Дело всего лишь в *представлении* (presentation).
Вам поможет использование класса [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm), который позволяет создавать желаемые паттерны.

Следует обратить внимание, что паттерны чувствительны к регистру. То есть, например, `MM` - не то же самое что `mm`.

Ну или начиная с Java 8, можно использовать пакет `java.time` и в частности `DateTimeFormatter`.

Шаги следующие:

1. Распарсили дату в формате `yyyy-MM-dd`
2. Увеличили ее на один день
3. Привели к представлению `dd.MM.yyyy`
4. Отослали на сервер